# How do I create a <div> table within another <div> table using relative width using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to embed a  table("anotherTable") within another  table("table"). 
The width of the cells are specified as percentages.

"table" contains 3 cells with width 10%, 80% and 10%.

"anotherTable" contains 5 cells with widths 20%, 20%, 20%, 20% and 20%.

I need the cell widths in "anotherTable" to be relative to cell 2 of "table". How can I achieve this?

Currently, the cell widths in "anotherTable" is view port specific.

Here is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/madathil/03u7947p/

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>test</title>

  <style> 
    *{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
    .cell { border: 1px solid red; border-style: none solid none none; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="table" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="row" >
        <div class="cell" style="width: 10%; background-color: powderblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell" style="width: 80%; background-color: pink; float: left;">
            <div class="anotherTable">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightgreen; float: left; border">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightred; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightyellow; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: orange; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cell" style="width: 10%; background-color: powderblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no table... Just divs and floated divs. You should use the correct display/tags if you really wanted a table that behaves like a table.

Comment: Why are you saying the width's are viewport specific? The only reason it happens is because of your borders.

Comment: @Salketer I see now, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-style: none solid none none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" style="width: 10%; background-color: powderblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell" style="width: 80%; background-color: pink; float: left;">
      <div class="anotherTable">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightgreen; float: left; border">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightred; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightyellow; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: orange; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell" style="width: 10%; background-color: powderblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div>
    </div>
```

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` this will make the borders count into the width you specify... Else you'd get 20% + 1px border, which would in turn result in more than 100% in total, hence why you got some cells that carried over a new line.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a `border` in `.cell`. So your width is: **(20% * 5) + 10px > 100%**.

So you have to use `box-sizing: border-box`:

```css
* {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}

.cell { 
  border: 1px solid red; 
  border-style: none solid none none; 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="table" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="cell" style="width: 10%; background-color: powderblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="cell" style="width: 80%; background-color: pink; float: left;">
      <div class="anotherTable">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightgreen; float: left; border">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightred; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightyellow; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: lightblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
          <div class="cell" style="width: 20%; background-color: orange; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell" style="width: 10%; background-color: powderblue; float: left;">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also added `clear: both` because you are using floats.